# Closed form of sum with ceil of logarithm.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've been practicing discrete math recently and I'm stuck on this problem. Could someone help me with this, give me some hint or direction? The problem is:

Find the closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^n \lceil{log_{2}k}\rceil$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A good approach is to write a small program giving say the 
 1000 first terms of the sequence... in order to be able to establish a conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p=\lfloor\log_2{n}\rfloor$, then
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=1}^n \lceil \log_2{k} \rceil&=\sum_{k=1}^{2^0}\lceil \log_2{k} \rceil+\sum_{k=2^0+1}^{2^1}\lceil \log_2{k} \rceil+\cdots+\sum_{k=2^{p-1}+1}^{2^p}\lceil \log_2{k} \rceil+\sum_{k=2^p+1}^n\lceil \log_2{k} \rceil\\
    &=0+1\cdot\left(2^1-2^0\right)+2\cdot\left(2^2-2^1\right)+\cdots+p\cdot\left(2^p-2^{p-1}\right)+(p+1)\cdot \left(n-2^p\right)\\
    &=1\cdot 2^0+2\cdot 2^1+\cdots +p\cdot 2^{p-1}+(p+1)\left(n-2^p\right)\\
    &=\sum_{i=1}^pi\cdot 2^{i-1}+(p+1)\left(n-2^p\right)\\
    &=(p-1)\cdot 2^p+(p+1)\left(n-2^p\right)+1
\end{align*}
Here are some explanations
\begin{align*}
    I&=\sum_{i=1}^pi\cdot 2^{i-1}\tag*{(1)}\\
    2I&=\sum_{i=1}^pi\cdot 2^{i}\tag*{(2)}
\end{align*}
You can make a difference between these two equations, then
\begin{align*}
    -I&=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}2^{i}-p\cdot 2^p=(1-p)\cdot 2^p-1\\
    I&=(p-1)\cdot 2^p+1
\end{align*}
So the proof is done.

Answer (score 1):

Observation being part of science, doing what @Jean Marie suggested in comments, the first $\lceil \log_2 (k)\rceil$ are
$$\{0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5\}$$
and the partial sums
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \lceil{\log_{2}k}\rceil$$ are
$$\{0,1,3,5,8,11,14,17,21,25,29,33,37,41,45,49,54,59,64,69\}$$ which are no more than

$$S_n=n \lceil \log_2 (n)\rceil -2^{\lceil \log_2 (n)\rceil }+1$$

$S_n$ is in fact the number of digits in the binary representation of all the numbers $1$ to $(n-1)$.

These numbers form sequence $A001855$ in $OEIS$ where you could find much more information.